# WinForms name chooser

Tags: winforms

I have a set of names (first, last, salutation) and need a control to allow users to select a single name using WinForms.  A ComboBox works fine if the there are ~20 names, but not so well when there are >100 names.

Can anyone recommend a name picker?  Perhaps an address book control that I could customize?  It's not too hard to write my own, but I have other wheels to invent.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what are your biggest gripes about the combobox? Is it because you don't have paging? Is it that you can't search properly?

Answer (score 1):

I'm giving you an answer that seems more like a feature request... :-) It can be very easy to use if you implement a control which behaviour is similar to the auto-completion feature of Google: foreach char inserted by the user, a window appears with only the names that match with the string inserted.
I think that it isn't so hard to implement, but I'm sorry, I can't give you a recommendation, only an advice :-)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Maurizio. To add to his answer:

The most commonly used interface which does exactly this is in email clients, where they auto-complete names (and/or email addresses) as you type them. Thunderbird is a pretty good example. These usually either auto-complete if there is only one match, or show a drop-down list of possible autocompletions you can pick from. In addition, a button next to the field usually allows you to browse the address book as a list.

I'd also suggest filtering the autocompletions available in the most useful ways: e.g. As you type "wi", you could filter it down to names like "[WI]lson, John", "Amery, [WI]lliam", and "[I]ving, [W]alter", making it easy to find people by their initials as well as first and surnames.

Comment: Is there an existing control available? As this is such a common requirement, reinventing the wheel seems not right, this is part of the question as well.

Comment: Several .net text entry controls allow you to provide an autocomplete list, and they wil do this for you. No doubt there are third party options that provide more comprehensive options. But that sort of little UI feature is fun to write :-)